# Active Directory and Firebase

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase to provide user's identity to my application that runs on GAE and **is accessible with web browser** and consumes Firebase secured endpoint.

The application is to be delivered as SaaS solution to business users, so I wonder if there is a possibility to provide SSO to the users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using Firebase's custom authentication, you can inform Firebase Authentication of any authentication scheme you implement.

Once you have the Active Directory SSO working, you [mint a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) and [inform Firebase about the authenticated user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem about a year ago. I made a Firebase function that after I authenticated towards Microsoft, created a custom token and with the UID that the user got from Microsoft Graph/AzureAD. Hope that this can help out

[Firebase custom Auth with Microsoft Azure / Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47075445/firebase-custom-auth-with-microsoft-azure-graph)